# Python Binning code and taking average

Tags: python, dataframe, binning

I am new to Python and am struggling with the following.
I have the following dataframe:

```
cat data
1   122.8099975
2   131.02
1   49.123999
2   122.5250015
3   40.86333217
2   61.40250025
2   122.5999985
3   35.02142771
3   246.320007
3   123.885002
3   61.942501
1   247.770004
1   123.885002

bins=array([  0,  20,  40,  60,  80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240, 260])
```

I want to create a new column by doing the following:

For each category `("cat")`, bin the data into `bins` and take the average of the count of items in each bin as illustrated by these spreadsheets:

[image]

Then assign the average to the relevant category in a new column:

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cut` and `crosstab`:

```
i = pd.cut(df.set_index('cat').data, bins=bins).reset_index()
j = pd.crosstab(i.data, i.cat)

cat         1  2  3
data               
(0, 20]     0  0  0
(20, 40]    0  0  1
(40, 60]    1  0  1
(60, 80]    0  1  1
(80, 100]   0  0  0
(100, 120]  0  0  0
(120, 140]  2  3  1
(140, 160]  0  0  0
(160, 180]  0  0  0
(180, 200]  0  0  0
(200, 220]  0  0  0
(220, 240]  0  0  0
(240, 260]  1  0  1
```

For the second part, use `mean`, compute the means, and use `map` to assign back to `df` -

```
df['average'] = df['cat'].map(j.mean())
df

    cat        data   average
0     1  122.809998  0.307692
1     2  131.020000  0.307692
2     1   49.123999  0.307692
3     2  122.525001  0.307692
4     3   40.863332  0.384615
5     2   61.402500  0.307692
6     2  122.599999  0.307692
7     3   35.021428  0.384615
8     3  246.320007  0.384615
9     3  123.885002  0.384615
10    3   61.942501  0.384615
11    1  247.770004  0.307692
12    1  123.885002  0.307692
```

Comment: This is useful, how do I go to the final stage of the "average" column in green ?

Comment: This code works 100%.  However I am finding the "crosstab" part is blowing my PC memory when the number of "cat" increases.  Is there a way of getting from "i" to the final "average" column that uses less memory?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use the numpy package for doing such statistical analysis.

You then simply start out by using [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to bin your data, and proceed from there to extract other statistics. Of course, for more advanced use-cases, it might be desirable to use something like scipy or pandas, but numpy is likely to serve your needs for most things and is these days a rather standard module.